# Logarithm formula proof

Tags: logarithms

Prove:

$$x^{\log(y)}=y^{\log(x)}$$

I have been trying this for the past 1 hour, still cant prove it.

I started with

$$\log_b(y)=m$$
$$\log_b(x)=n$$

To show: $$x^m = y^n$$

How do i proceed? :

Comment: Take logs of both sides.

Comment: @Chinny84 Thank you but I still dont get it. how do we go after $\log _b(x^{\log _b (y)})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can take logs on both sides because taking the log preserves the equality i.e.
$$
\log a = \log b \iff a = b
$$
in short, we can still prove the statement if are working the logarithm of the equality.

Anyway,

$$
\log \left(x^{\log y}\right) = \log (y) \log (x) 
$$
similarly 
$$
\log \left(y^{\log x}\right) = \log (x) \log (y) 
$$
here I used $\log a^b = b \log a$.

Comment: How did u get $$\log \left(x^{\log y}\right) = \log (y) \log (x)$$?? Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand about logarithms?

Comment: Ohh i  got you! you used power formula!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\large x^a=\left(e^{\log x}\right)^a=e^{(\log x)\cdot a}$

Comment: Now where did you get that from

Comment: @TimKrul, $$\large x^a=e^{\ln(x^a)}=e^{a\ln x}$$

Comment: The idea is to note that the function $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln x$ are inverse of each other.

Comment: Thnk you answerer!

Comment: @TimKrul: edited, more clear now? I didn't know from where did I get it from, "I have known it for ages".

Answer (score 1):

Start with the following equality:

$$\log(x)\log(y)=\log(x)\log(y)\\ \implies e^{\log(x)\log(y)}=e^{\log(x)\log(y)}\\ \implies \left(e^{\log x}\right)^{\log y}=\left(e^{\log y}\right)^{\log x}\\ \implies x^{\log y}=y^{\log x}$$

Identities used:

- $e^{\log x}=x$
- $(a^m)^n=(a^n)^m=a^{mn}$

Comment: We also used the fact that $x=y\implies e^x=e^y$

Comment: Thank u but most of it went above my head!

Comment: @TimKrul, please tell me which part you're having difficulty with. I'll try to help as much as I can.